# Detecting Race Conditions Without Mutual Exclusion Implementation

Tags: concurrency, locking

I know we can detect and overcome race conditions by implementing mutual exclusion using atomic lock variables, but is there any way to detect race condition without implementing the mutual exclusion?

The mutual exclusion increases the overhead up to a great deal, so I was thinking of a way to overcome race conditions without any additional overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization doesn't need to increase overhead much at all. There are usually fairly cheap suitable ways to solve a problem. If you're having trouble with that, if you post the details of your scenario and what synchronization techniques you're using to protect it we might be able to offer some suggestions.

As far as avoiding the need for synchronization, there really is no good way. It's a problem you just have to deal with in concurrent programming. In many cases you can avoid needing multiple threads completely, and in other cases you can isolate the threads as much as possible and reduce the need for synchronization to a few critical places. For example, in many cases I like to use a message thread concept where I have one thread responsible for all bookkeeping and data access. Worker threads then post messages to this thread (using a synchronized queue) for processing. Doing this means I need only provide a synchronized message queue, and all other operations can proceed independently.

Hope this helps! Feel free to post some more details if you want more specific ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Your mention of a "synchronized queue" might be better explained.  In your message queue example a good  candidate is LinkedBlockingQueue - which uses locks not synchronized. A casual reader would likely believe you intend "synchronized" within the queue methods.

Comment: @javadba Good clarification, thanks. In C# the [`Queue.Synchronized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) getter can be used to create a thread-safe wrapper around a `Queue`.